# Searching for numbers and characters with Lucene

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm trying to figure out how to make Lucene do what I need. We search through a legislation guidance and need to find results for search phrases like "legislation paragraph 9.8.1". This should return anything that matches that string. There is a problem with StandardAnalyzer as it doesn't return results if the actual text is "legislation paragraph 9.8.1." or "legislation paragraph 9.8.1(a)". I am trying very simple queries like:

```
bodyText: "legislation paragraph 9.8.1*"
```

and

```
bodyText: "legislation paragraph 9.8.1"
```

My questions are:

1) How does Lucene understand query like the following?

```
bodyText: "legislation paragraph 9.8*"
```

The star is obviously not handled as a wildcard.

3) Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do? The set of result for a search phrase "legislation paragraph 9" must contain all results from query "legislation paragraph 9.8". In other words I want to achieve a simple case insensitive string match.

The Lucene version in our build is 2.9.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I did a quick test, and it works fine for me, using the standard analyzer (for both indexing and searching). Is the field `bodyText` analyzed or not? Are you using the same analyzers for indexing and searching? Take a look at [Luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/), which is a helpful tool to analyze such issues.

Comment: Hi yes it is analyzed and I use same analyzer for searching (StandardAnalyzer).